# Materialize app and realistic texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, texture-baking

i used the materialize app by bounding box software to create the textures and it works great in the app the textures really look good but when applying them to the mesh the texture don't look realistic anymore.

The texture's when combined in the materialize app look like this: [image]

But when i apply them to the mesh they look like this : [image]

and the node setup i use for the textures : [image]

Please and Thanks

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your material setup seem to be wrong.

Check my example image for creating PBR setups in Blender. It maybe helps you:

[image]

You can read my short article for this topic, if you like:

[How to setup PBR materials in Blender](https://www.christoph-werner.de/2019/09/20/pbr-materials-based-on-substance-textures/)

Comment: hey i tried your setup but when i use "experimental" and render i get "out of memory" error. So, for now i am going to use your node setup and see the render.

Comment: omg it worked, thanks for the help i appreciate it.